# Fail to import rospy

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Guys

I'm trying to implement a code to call ROS topics inside a Python code.

When i try to import rospy and roslib I have the message:

```
import roslib
ImportError: No module named roslib
```

my initial code is:

```
from collections import deque
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2
import os # incluido para chamar comando do linux.
import time #incluido para utilizar o delay
import roslib
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288170/fail-to-import-rospy/) by [brunoribeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/34580/brunoribeiro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-04-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-10**:
This is not a solution, but: you don't need to import `roslib` any longer in a `rospy` script. Unless you're using some functionality from it of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to have the ROS Environment sourced in the terminal where you run this.
Follow the tutorial about  [Setting up a ROS Workspace](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment#Create_a_ROS_Workspace).

Remember to call `source <PATH_TO_YOUR_WORKSPACE>/devel/setup.bash` in every new terminal you open.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kharkad](https://answers.ros.org/users/34550/kharkad/) on 2018-04-11**:
Or even better, writte down the `source <PATH_TO_YOUR_WORKSPACE>/devel/setup.bash` into your .bashrc file, which will source the setup file automatically everytime you open a new terminal.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-04-12**:
@kharkad you are correct.

Though once you start working with multiple workspaces this can lead to a lot of confusion. Thus, until you know what this is about, I personally think it helps people understand what is required and why if you have to do that manually...